# Where was Treissa (Werra valley, lower Hesse area)

Tags: germany, hesse

I'm looking at a marriage record from Wanfried, Germany, from 1746:

[image]

> Den 10t. Febr. wurden joh. Werner Laagis [?]
> witbr, Henrich Wilhelm Laagii sohn, und Maria
> Catharina, tochter Johannis Schweitzer, metzgers
> aus Treissa eheliche tochter, [post?] [zweien?] pro-
> clamationen, und war [?] [vieler?] sie [?]
> Hochzeit machen, im Hause copuliret.

I've considered that it may have meant Treysa, but Treysa is 75km away to the west, and looking at the church books from Treysa, I find no entries for any Schweitzers there.

[This map](https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/edit?mid=1_cHy99goGI3DEpQ_6ma9HSY9CxEXQ26H&usp=sharing) indicates any town in the area where I've found any Schweitzers; bright green dots are 1500-1700, while olive dots indicate 1700-present; the orange dots are my own Schweitzer lineage.  Wanfried is the olive-colored moon dot in the upper right; Treysa is down at the extreme lower-left.  So if it didn't mean Treysa, where is/was "Treissa"?

Note, Wanfried itself is olive-green due to a Schweitzer from my own line who came from Creuzburg in 1790; this would have been 44 years earlier, roughly at the same time my own Schweitzer-line ancestor was just being born in Mihla.  Also, all known Schweitzers in the Werra valley were either millers or farmers, not butchers.

EDIT: Image of the map, for anyone having issues with the above link.
[image]

Comment: The map is inaccessible to anyone not logged in to a Google account. Can you post the image into the question?